# Java 1.3.1 on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to launch a Java 1.3 VM (x86) in Windows 7 (x64).

Whenever any AWT-related code is executed,
the following is printed to stderr:

```
Assertion failed: glyph != NULL, file ../../../src/share/native/sun/awt/font/t2k/truetype.c, line 2133
```

In the Windows Event Log, I see:

```
msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.7601.17744, time stamp: 0x4eeaf722
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0006680c
Faulting process id: 0x1bdc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfbc7d957f19ce
Faulting application path: C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.3.1_28\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: d351babf-2870-11e4-8ed2-005056c00008
```

I've tried various compatibility modes for `java.exe`, with no luck. There's a "private" 32-bit `msvcrt.dll` copy under `C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.3.1_28\jre\bin` which apparently isn't used at all.

Additionally, I'm using the Classic windows theme (Aero is turned off).

Any idea how to make Java AWT operational?

Comment: Yes, yes there is: Upgrade.

Comment: @Brad: thanks, but I'm trying to get Sun Forte for Java 2.0 running, and it relies on certain classes in `tools.jar` which are no longer available in 1.4+ JDK versions.

Comment: I think your only sensible option is to set up an OS that is actually supported by the 1.3 release and use that (e.g. Windows XP in a VM).

Comment: @Bass - Thanks for taking the sarcasm humorously ;).  I think Durandal is right... a VM might be a better option for you.  Do you have Windows 7 Ultimate?  I think there's a VM for XP built into that.

Comment: @Brad Well, while Windows XP seems to have the best binary compatibility (only Solaris may be better in this regard), I managed to run Java 1.3 on bare metal on my (not so good in terms of binary compatibility) Linux box -- just had to add `libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3` from [compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-132.7.2.i386.rpm](http://vault.centos.org/4.9/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-132.7.2.i386.rpm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four years late posting here, but in case it helps someone, I also encountered this problem with 1.3.1_28 on Windows Vista, but 1.3.1_20 seems to work fine.